# How to change canonicalization method

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-dsig

does anyone know how to change the CanonicalizationMethod property in `xadesjs`? I know it is using `xmldsigjs` underneath but I cannot find a solution to change it. I mean the CanonicalizationMethod for the whole SignedInfo property (not the transforms for the references). Currently (by default) I get a document that has CanonicalizationMethod set to C14N:

```
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
```

I want to change it to EXC-C14N:

```
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution. In case anybody needs it, you can directly assign it with:

```
let signedXml = new XAdES.SignedXml();
signedXml.XmlSignature.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";
```

Comment: This is right way. There is no signing option for SignedInfo canonicalization method https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/xmldsigjs#options

Comment: I created issue https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/xmldsigjs/issues/21